# Turning on TRUSTWORTHY with a dacpac

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, sql-server-data-tools, dac

I am creating a database with an SSDT database project and deploying as a dacpac. A .NET assembly is part of the project and during deployment installation fails with the following error message:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'xyz' failed because assembly
>   'xyz' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The
>   assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the
>   database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database
>   has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed
>   with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login
>   with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.

The dbo is 'sa'. I have gone into the project properties and checked "Trustworthy" under the Miscellaneous tab. However, I still get the error and when I run

```
select name, is_trustworthy_on from sys.databases
```

I see that `is_trustworthy_on` is 0. It seems this setting has no effect. After searching, I found the following:

> Some database options, such as TRUSTWORTHY, DB_CHAINING, and
>   HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY, cannot be adjusted as part of the deployment
>   process.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210569.aspx

The word *adjusted* implies *changed* to me. This is a new database. However, if it is true even for new databases, why does the setting exist in the dialog? Do I need to script this as part of the pre-deployment?

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question, but you could try signing the assembly instead of making the database trustworthy.

Comment: It's possible, but less than ideal. I'm under contract to automate the as-is state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the "Trustworthy" check-box in the "Miscellaneous" tab checked, you should only need to ensure that you have the option for "Deploy database properties" checked (or set to true). This option will be in different places, depending on exactly how you are publishing. Some places include:

- Going to the "Build" menu and selecting "Publish {project name}..."

  - "Publish Database" wizard appears.
  - Click on the "Advanced..." button
  - Top check-box is for "Deploy database properties"

- Using **SqlPackage.exe**:

  - Passing in via a profile file: `<ScriptDatabaseOptions>True</ScriptDatabaseOptions>`
  - Passing in via command-line: `/p:ScriptDatabaseOptions = True`

- Using **MSDeploy** with the dbSqlPackage provider:

  - Option is: `ScriptDatabaseOptions=True`

Comment: Way to leave a guy is suspense! ;)

Comment: @Swoogan Sorry, had to check a few places first ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Cargo cult programming. I copied another deployment script that had /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=False in it. I clearly didn't know what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a message to say you must be a sysadmin?? The user who does the deployment needs to be in the sysadmin group. There are some settings that are wrapped in:

```
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin') = 1
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
                   WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE sp_executesql N'ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
                SET TRUSTWORTHY ON 
                WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE';
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'The database settings cannot be modified. You must be a SysAdmin to apply these settings.';
    END
```

Comment: The login used for the deployment is part of the sysadmin role. However, when I generate the script and search for trustworthy, I don't get any results. How did you get it to generate that?